# Find size of an array in a document

Tags: mongodb

I need to find size of an array in a document.

```
Example:
{
  "_id" : "2",
  "coord" : [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

I need size of coord.

How do i find it? Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the aggregation framework.

```
    db.temps.aggregate([{$unwind:"$coord"},{$group:{_id:"$_id", coord_length:{$sum:1}}}])
```

If you have multiple documents with different coordinates, it will show the length of that array.
You could add the $match operator for finding specific documents.

Answer (score 0):

say `ex` is a variable referenced to the example item mentioned above

```
ex = { "_id" : "2", "coord" : [1,2,3,4,5] }
```

you can get the length of `"coord"` by

```
ex["coord"].length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) aggregation operator for that:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate({$project: {size: {$size: '$coord'}}})
```

Output

```javascript
{ "_id": "2", "size": 5 }
```

Note that the `$size` operator was added in version 2.6.